# How to split int value without input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

code below works well  but i want to change 'input(row, col)' to (1, 1) so i can modify
value inside code without input, but when i change it it gives this error

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

what is the solution?
thank you.

```
import random

class Tic:

    def __init__(self):
        self.board = []
    
    def create_board(self):
        for i in range(8):
            row = []
            for j in range(8):
                row.append('-')
            self.board.append(row)

    def fix_spot(self, row, col, player):
        self.board[row][col] = player


    def show_board(self):
        for row in self.board:
            print(row)

    def start(self):
        player = 'O'
        T.create_board()
        row, col = list(map(int, input("row, col: ").split()))
        self.fix_spot(row -1, col-1, player)
        T.show_board()

T = Tic()
T.start()
```

Comment: Judging by the error message, you are using Python-2.7, not python -3.x. Please update the tags.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that all you need to do is replace the line

```
row, col = list(map(int, input("row, col: ").split()))
```

with

```
row, col = (1,1)
```

Comment: can't believe it was that simple, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use `row` and `col` elsewhere in the function, you could put the value direct in the `fix_spot` arguments

```py
    def start(self):
        player = 'O'
        T.create_board()
        self.fix_spot(0, 0, player)
        T.show_board()
```

Or set a default value in `fix_spot`

```py
    def fix_spot(self, player, row=0, col=0):
        self.board[row][col] = player

    def start(self):
        player = 'O'
        T.create_board()
        self.fix_spot(player)
        T.show_board()
```